# Extracting out the important information from a web page when provided with only the URL

Tags: web-services, rss

What I'm referring to is what apps like Facebook and Twitter do when someone posts a link. They are able to convert that link into a title, an important image and (sometimes) a short summary.

What I'm asking is: is there some trick to this using tags, rss or metadata or do you have to sign up for a web service which does this for you or write the code yourself, downloading the HTML and parsing it to extract out a guess to the components you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ogp.me - They all use the open graph protocol or others. The answers are in the meta tags.